# How do I add 'Severity' to 'Product Back Log' work item types in TFS?

Tags: tfs

What is the easiest way to add a Severity type item to the 'Product Back Log' work item like there is in the 'Bug' Work Item in TFS 2013.   It should have the same options as well as the 'Bug' work item.

Answer (score 2):

The easyest way would be to just copy the field from bug.

If you are going to make any customisations you should put the process under source control. Download the process template (not the exported work items) and put the whole thing in your source control system. Then just open the bug in notepad and copy the field. Stick it into the same location in the PBI and then use the witadmin command to push the result into TFS.